# Why a servlet couldn't get jasper report path ?

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports, filenotfoundexception

I am a new comer to web application development in java and I am using net beans for this .

I am created a web application to print a jasper report in client side.I used a servlet for this purpose. In here I gained above problem . I gave file path in different ways . But finally I have to put file path with the current working directory(partition) . But I want to give it with the path of the src folder .

Also I've gave this path with the project name . But I had gain following exception .

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jasper\JasperReport\src\java\jasper\Report.jrxml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:222)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:193)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:184)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:224)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:539)
    at jasper.Show.processRequest(Show.java:61)
    at jasper.Show.doGet(Show.java:113)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Jasper\JasperReport\src\java\jasper\Report.jrxml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.load(JRXmlLoader.java:217)
    ... 28 more
Jasper\JasperReport\src\java\jasper\Report.jrxml
```

1. List item

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to help you if you pasted fragment of your code. But I'll try anyway.

Method `JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile` takes as an argument a path to jrxml file, either absoulute or relative to working directory. And I think you shouldn't use that method in this case.

In your case I think it would be better to use something like this:

```
InputStream jrxmlFileStream = getClass.getResourceAsStream("/path/to/file.jrxml");
// this path should be relative to src folder
JasperCompileManager.compileReportToStream(jrxmlFileStream, reportFileOutputStream);
// reportFileOutputStream - an OutputStream that writes to destination file
```

(I've omitted here any exception handling or resources closing)

Comment: :-   String jsaperFile="C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Terance\\Jasper\\JasperReport\\src\\java\\jasper\\Report.jrxml";                                                                       and this is for jasper report ,                                                                               String report=JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(jsaperFile);

Comment: @Barrier You should add the  above comment to your actual question itself.